# Как при закрытии "всплывающего" блока с роликом YouTube сам ролик "ставить на паузу"?

Tags: jquery, javascript, youtube

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией: на странице есть некоторый элемент управления по клику на котором "всплывает" (jquery-метод `show`) блок с youtub'овским кодом с плеером. Нажимаешь кнопку "закрыть" в блоке и этот блок исчезает (jquery-метод `.hide`). Но видео не останавливается :) Точнее во всех браузерах вроде как все ок, но в хроме даже при скрытом блоке слышно, что "где-то там" видео все еще проигрывается...

Логично было бы при нажатии кнопки "закрыть" сначала ставить на паузу ролик, а после скрывать блок с плеером. Это возможно? Или есть другой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть способ просто удалять блок с плеером (jquery-метод .remove).

Comment: т.е. пользователь закрывает блок, блок удаляется, а после пользователь снова жмахает на кнопку открытия блока с видео, а блока уже нету :) Не очень хороший вариант.

Comment: Пользователь жмет на кнопку - блок формируется.

Comment: И youtube видео кешируются, таким образом, если пользователь "закроет" видео - оно не будет грузиться, если откроет - все что уже грузилось восстановится.

@xhr - Когда прочитал "а блока уже нету" немного засомневался в вашей компетентности =)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, можете сомневаться даже много. Мне-то что до этого. remove
http://api.jquery.com/remove/
удаляет элементы из DOM. Поэтому если удалить скрыть (hide) блок и сделать для него remove, то его физически на странице больше не будет. Теперь пользователь (не перезагружая страницу) снова вызывает (show) этот оверлей... и что ему должно показаться? - нету уже блока - нету :)

Comment: @ling можно формировать содержимое блока "ajax'ом", но оно формируется сервером при создании страницы. И переделывать этот момент совсем не хочется - точно есть способ проще. Так что удалять блок - идея плохая.

Comment: @xhr - таки не зря сомневался. Все что вам нужно это завернуть ролик в div, перед удалением сохранить html видео. Соответственно при раскрытии - восстанавливать.

И вам-же написали  - "Пользователь жмет на кнопку - блок формируется", что тут непонятного? Какой remove? O_o

Comment: @xhr, при формировании страницы запоминайте id ролика и javascript'ом формируйте блок видео. Даже при удалении блока по id ролика его можно будет сформировать заново.  
А если у вас 5 видео на странице, формировать блоки будете для них всех одновременно?