# Управление роликом YouTube через JavaSctipt

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Нашёл подобную задачу, но так и не разобрался.
[Как при закрытии "всплывающего" блока с роликом YouTube сам ролик "ставить на паузу"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/71086/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-youtube-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%83)

Задача: при закрытии всплывающего окна ролик должен останавливаться. Код в окне:

```
<iframe class='youtu' width="700" height="394" src="ссылка на сам ролик" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Так понял, что при закрытии окна необходимо выполнить `$('#playerObject')[0].stopVideo();`, но где брать `#playerObject`? Или его необходимо самому прописать в `<iframe>`? Пробовал — не помогло.

Естественное в чём разбирался — [JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=ru#Playback_controls), но очевидно, что результата нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации к Youtube API указано:

> Для вызова методов API проигрывателя необходимо сначала получить ссылку на объект проигрывателя. Для этого вызовите getElementById() для тега object или embed, в котором содержится проигрыватель SWF, если для встраивания проигрывателя SWF используется SWFObject.

Следовательно, Вам надо встраивать видео не через фрейм а через swf object. И надо указать для embed или object id, и тогда по этому id вы сможете управлять плеером

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Ещё раз внимательно прочитал документацию по api и всё само собой вдруг стало понятно.
Всё великолепно работает!